# how do I run my telegraf bot on AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, telegram, telegraf

So I have this simple telegraf bot that works when I run it locally with node. I also managed to create some simple Lambda functions, but I can't figure out how to actually run the bot on the lambda. I tried this:

```
const { Telegraf } = require("telegraf");

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const bot = new Telegraf(<token goes here>);
  bot.start((ctx) => ctx.reply(""));
  bot.launch();

  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify('OK'),
};

return response;
};
```

But I'm sure this is not the way it is supposed to be implemented

Comment: Do you paste the code on aws? It worked?

Comment: Why lambda function? you have to pay a lot of money for a simple task, and your bot is only alive in 15min.

Comment: Is your requirement for an enterprise, something for real users or just a proof of concept? Nothing is free in this life

Answer (score 1):

You should use `bot.handleUpdate(update)` but don't forget to parse message before, because it could be a string, and even more – base64 encoded string, e.g.:

```js
const { Telegraf } = require("telegraf")

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  let message
  try {
    if (!event.body) {
      throw new Error("unknown request type")
    }
    let body = event.body
    if (event.isBase64Encoded) {
      body = base64Decode(body)
    }
    message = JSON.parse(body)
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: error.message,
    }
  }
  try {
    const botToken = await getToken() // e.g. get bot token from AWS Secrets Manager
    const bot = new Telegraf(botToken)
    await bot.handleUpdate(message)
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: error.message,
    }
  }
}

function base64Decode(str) {
  return Buffer.from(str, "base64").toString("utf8")
}
```

Comment: i've tried so many suggestions. telegraf's v4 documentation is not as informative. this one worked!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with telegraf, however, if you must have it on Lambda function, you can add its package as Lambda layer.

See what Lambda layer and how to leverage it in the following aws [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html).

By the way, like everyone mentioned above in the comment section, Lambda has limited resource such 15 minutes execution time as well as Lambda is one of  expensive AWS resources compare to EC2.
Also if telegraf is a heavy package or its process takes longer than 15 minutes, the Lambda function will be failed and you will have to configure DLQ.

Maybe for these reasons, people don't recommend you to run telegraf on Lambda function.

Idealy, you can find more architecture using Fargate or EC2.